# Linear map $L$ from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $L^2=-Id$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a linear endomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that is the square root of $-Id$? If not is there one for $\mathbb{R}^n$ where n is odd?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, an an endomorphism $A$, of $\mathbb{R}^3$ has a real eigenvalue since it characteristic polynomial has degree 3, if $A(u)=cu, c\in\mathbb{R}, A^2(u)=c^2u=-u$ implies that $c^2=-1$ impossible.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Use the multiplicative property of the determinant.